# Extracting phrases and words with Apache Tika

Tags: java, text-processing, apache-tika

I'm facing an issue with the extracting texts and phrases using Apache Tika.

I made a unit test where it seems to be missing some expected elements and has additional unexpected elements in the actual results.

Here's the `TextExtractor` class implementation:

```java
public class TextExtractor {

    public String[] extractPhrasesAndWords(InputStream stream) throws IOException, TikaException, SAXException {
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, new ParseContext());

        String content = handler.toString();

        // Splitting into phrases
        String[] phrases = content.split(": ");

        // Splitting into words
        String[] words = content.split("\\s+");

        // Combine both arrays
        String[] result = Arrays.copyOf(phrases, phrases.length + words.length);
        System.arraycopy(words, 0, result, phrases.length, words.length);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And here's the corresponding JUnit test, `TextExtractorTest`:

```java
public class TextExtractorTest {

    @Test
    public void testExtractPhrasesAndWords() throws IOException, TikaException, SAXException {
        String complexHtml = "<html><body>" +
                "<div>" +
                "<h2>Gravenhurst, or Thoughts on Good and Evil</h2>" +
                "<p>William Henry Smith (1808 - 1872)</p>" +
                "<p>Complete | Collaborative | English</p>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div>" +
                "<h2>The Voyagers: Being Legends and Romances of Atlantic Discovery</h2>" +
                "<p>Pádraic Colum (1881 - 1972)</p>" +
                "<p>Complete | Collaborative | English</p>" +
                "</div>" +
                // add other mock listings here as needed
                "</body></html>";

        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(complexHtml.getBytes());

        TextExtractor extractor = new TextExtractor();
        String[] result = extractor.extractPhrasesAndWords(stream);

        // expected array here
        String[] expected = {
            "Gravenhurst, or Thoughts on Good and Evil",
            "William Henry Smith (1808 - 1872)",
            "Complete | Collaborative | English",
            "The Voyagers",
            "Being Legends and Romances of Atlantic Discovery",
            "Pádraic Colum (1881 - 1972)",
            "Complete | Collaborative | English",
            // individual words and symbols
            "Gravenhurst,",
            "or",
            "Thoughts",
            "on",
            "Good",
            "and",
            "Evil",
            "William",
            "Henry",
            "Smith",
            "(1808",
            "-",
            "1872)",
            "Complete",
            "|",
            "Collaborative",
            "|",
            "English",
            "The",
            "Voyagers",
            "Being",
            "Legends",
            "and",
            "Romances",
            "of",
            "Atlantic",
            "Discovery",
            "Pádraic",
            "Colum",
            "(1881",
            "-",
            "1972)",
            "Complete",
            "|",
            "Collaborative",
            "|",
            "English"
        };

        Set<String> expectedSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(expected));
        Set<String> resultSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(result));

        // Check for missing elements in the expected array
        for (String expectedElement : expected) {
            if (!resultSet.contains(expectedElement)) {
                System.out.println("Missing from actual: " + expectedElement);
            }
        }

        // Check for additional elements in the actual array
        for (String actualElement : result) {
            if (!expectedSet.contains(actualElement)) {
                System.out.println("Additional in actual: " + actualElement);
            }
        }

        assertArrayEquals(expected, result);
    }
}
```

The test output indicates that some elements are missing from the actual results and there are additional unexpected elements:

```
Missing from actual: Gravenhurst, or Thoughts on Good and Evil
Missing from actual: William Henry Smith (1808 - 1872)
Missing from actual: Complete | Collaborative | English
Missing from actual: The Voyagers
Missing from actual: Being Legends and Romances of Atlantic Discovery
Missing from actual: Pádraic Colum (1881 - 1972)
Missing from actual: Complete | Collaborative | English
Missing from actual: Voyagers:
Additional in actual: Gravenhurst, or Thoughts on Good and Evil
William Henry Smith (1808 - 1872)
Complete | Collaborative | English
Additional in actual: The Voyagers
Additional in actual: Being Legends and Romances of Atlantic Discovery
Additional in actual: Pádraic Colum (1881 - 1972)
Additional in actual: Complete | Collaborative | English
```

Moreover, the assertion fails with the following message:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: array lengths differ,
Expected: 44
Actual: 39
```

I have already reviewed the implementation of the `TextExtractor` class, and it seems to be splitting the content correctly into phrases and words. However, the actual results don't match the expected results.

Any insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Here's the string content from Tika handler:

```
Gravenhurst, or Thoughts on Good and Evil
William Henry Smith (1808 - 1872)
Complete | Collaborative | English

The Voyagers: Being Legends and Romances of Atlantic Discovery
Pádraic Colum (1881 - 1972)
Complete | Collaborative | English
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the HTML that Tika generates via the Body content handler?